# Method call not working (probably simple and i'm just not getting it)

Tags: java

Receiving the error The method set question(String) is undefined for the type TriviaJava  can't figure out what I've done wrong thanks for any help

```
       //Class to create a trivia question
        import java.util.*;
        public class Trivia {
            private String question;
            private String answer;

            public String getQuestion() {
                return question;
            }

            public void setQuestion(String q) {
                question = q;
            }

            public String getAnswer() {
                return answer;
            }

            public void setAnswer(String a) {
                answer = a;
            }
        }


          //method call and use
            import java.util.Scanner;
            class ManyManyHappy{
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                    Trivia t = new Trivia();{
                    t.setQuestion("some question");
                    t.setAnswer("some answer");
                    System.out.println("Here's the question: " + t.getQuestion());
                    System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
                    String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(t.getAnswer()))
                        System.out.println("That's right - congratulations!");
                    else {
                        System.out.println("I'm sorry, that's not correct.");
                        System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + t.getAnswer());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Error: The method setAnswer(String) is undefined for the type Trivia

Comment: Is `ManyManyHappy` supposed to be an inner class?

Comment: No its they're in two separate files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManyManyHappy` is an Inner Class and it contains the `main` method which is forbidden. You have two options for solving this.

---

## 1. Static Nested Class

Declare `ManyManyHappy` as a static class so that `main` is accessible.

```
public class ManyManyHappy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        StackOverflow t = new StackOverflow();{
        t.setQuestion("some question");
        t.setAnswer("some answer");
        System.out.println("Here's the question: " + t.getQuestion());
        System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(t.getAnswer()))
            System.out.println("That's right - congratulations!");
        else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, that's not correct.");
            System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + t.getAnswer());
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

---

## 2. Separate Classes

Make two separate class files: `ManyManyHappy.java` and `Trivia.java`

**Trivia.java**

```
public class Trivia{

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String q) {
        question = q;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String a) {
        answer = a;
    }
}
```

**ManyManyHappy.java**

```
public class ManyManyHappy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        StackOverflow t = new StackOverflow();{
        t.setQuestion("some question");
        t.setAnswer("some answer");
        System.out.println("Here's the question: " + t.getQuestion());
        System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(t.getAnswer()))
            System.out.println("That's right - congratulations!");
        else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, that's not correct.");
            System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + t.getAnswer());
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh these are in two separate files already inside the same project

Comment: Are they inside the same package?

Comment: Yes I just checked again to be certain